# "Cross-Origin Request Blocked" error when using my web app over TOR

Tags: linux, flutter, firebase, nginx, tor

I know there are hundreds, (maybe more) similar questions on here, I checked almost all of them but none was helpful because I think my issue is totally different.

I developed a web app  (A chat web app) using Flutter and Firebase that can be used and run normally on normal browsers e.g; Chrome, Safari, Firefox, .. etc, however, when I run it on tor it loads perfectly, but only when I try to log in or register I get these two errors in the tor browser console:`

```
Cross-Origin Request Blocked: The Same Origin Policy disallows reading the remote resource at https://identitytoolkit.googleapis.com/v1/accounts:signInWithPassword?key=AIzaSyDp0fmvGxlSPXR8_4DVW6oKNBTKUFODDSs. (Reason: CORS header ‘Access-Control-Allow-Origin’ missing). Status code: 403.

Cross-Origin Request Blocked: The Same Origin Policy disallows reading the remote resource at https://identitytoolkit.googleapis.com/v1/accounts:signInWithPassword?key=AIzaSyDp0fmvGxlSPXR8_4DVW6oKNBTKUFODDSs. (Reason: CORS request did not succeed). Status code: (null)`
```

Not to mention, I can still log in / register on tor if I use the original hostname of the web app (clearnet version), but the onion link that I got from tor for my web app while setting up the hidden service is what causing the errors, so I don't know if it is the tor or Nginx causing the main problem..

I tried using this in nginx configuration:

`

```
server {
    listen 8444;
    server_name mysite.onion;

    location / {
        root /var/www/mysite;
        index index.html;

       # Add CORS headers
        add_header 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' 'https://mysite.onion' always;
        add_header 'Access-Control-Allow-Methods' 'GET, POST, OPTIONS' always;
        add_header 'Access-Control-Allow-Headers' 'DNT,User-Agent,X-Requested-With,If-Modified-Since,Cache-Control,Con>

       # Optional: Add more CORS headers if needed
        add_header 'Access-Control-Allow-Credentials' 'true';
        add_header 'Access-Control-Expose-Headers' 'Content-Length,Content-Range';

 }`
```

I also added the onion domain in the firebase console (Authorised Domains) ..

Any help would be highly appreciated..

Comment: The browser is refusing to connect to `https://identitytoolkit.googleapis.com/v1/accounts:signInWithPassword?...` because *that host* isn't affirmatively allowing the origin of the site on tor.  Using the onion service changes the hostname that the browser sees, no?

Comment: the original hostname is something like flash9837.web.app, but that is hosted with firebase, now I transferred my web app to be hosted on tor using nginx server,

Comment: CORS is based on the origin scheme, and port of the origin of the request.  So if the origin changes, the configuration on `identitytoolkit.googleapis.com` will have to change accordingly.

Comment: Okay thank u for ur comments, but what exactly should I do ?